# Android Studio Seems to be stuck while Downloading kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.pom

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am having a android project which was using java code alone. But I wanted to use Both Kotlin as well as Java for development.

So I just added a `Kotlin` Class file to my project via **`New -> Kotlin File/ Class`**

Since this was the first time the project is exposed to Kotlin it added some dependencies to the Gradle file automatically which is expected.

But now I synced my project but it seems to be android studio stuck while Downloading `kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.pom` it almost 22 minutes now

[image: Reference Image]

I have a stable internet connection but it doesn't seem to complete at all

For your reference :

**app level build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.morningbell.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }


}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0"                    // added automatically actually it was ktx:+ i replaced it to 1.3.0
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72" // added automatically, it was jdk7:$kotlin_version I replaced version
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Project level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"  // added automatically 
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I just wanted to know Is there anything wrong with Gradle files? I appreciate your help

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got rid of this error by changing

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72"
```

to

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
```

and by adding

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

to top of the app level `build.gradle` file

Comment: MARK THESE AS THE ANSWERS SO THAT PEOPLE DO NOT GET CONFUSED!!!!